# Falha ao carregar uma função com seletor jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ao clicar em um botão, preciso que carregue minha função JS.
 Para carregar essa função, ao clicar no botão só funciona se informar no *button* com o atributo *onclick*, informando o nome da função. 
Quando tento acessar através do seletor da classe do botão, a função não carrega.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs excl-receita"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
```

A função JS que pretendo utilizar:

```
$('.excl-receita').off('click').on('click', function () { });
```

Comment: Pq está utilizando `.off`? Seria apenas `$('.excl-receita').on('click', function () { });`

Comment: Com .off ou sem, não funciona.

Comment: Mesmo com `.off` deveria funcionar. Só questionei o seu uso rs. Pode não estar funcionando por várias razões: o elemento é dinâmico? O código está antes ou depois do elemento?

Comment: O JS é carregado antes da página. E o elemento é dinâmico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente com

```
$('body').on('click', '.excl-receita', function () { });
```